# ng-submit doesn't work in angular js

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, ng-submit

I know that there are a lot of other similar questions but I didn't find the answer there.

```
<html ng-app="app" ng-controller="AppController">    
...
    <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search" ng-submit="alert()">
         <div class="form-group">
             <input type="text" class="form-control search" ng-model="text" />
         </div>
         <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default icon-default icon-search">Submit                          </button>
    </form>
</html>
```

Comment: That's nice - what's the actual issue, an error? What is `alert()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to submit the form by adding ng-click in the  button tag and call submit function by passing your form in the ng-click. The function is where you write your logic in the controller.                                                                                 submit

Answer (score 3):

You cant use `alert` (window.alert) function in angular as you normally do in plain javascript. This is example from angular `$window` service [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24window):

```
<script>
  function Ctrl($scope, $window) {
    $scope.greeting = 'Hello, World!';
    $scope.doGreeting = function(greeting) {
        $window.alert(greeting);
    };
  }
</script>
<div ng-controller="Ctrl">
  <input type="text" ng-model="greeting" />
  <button ng-click="doGreeting(greeting)">ALERT</button>
</div>
```

If you put `doGreeting` (name it as you want) function in your controller and inject `$window`, then your example should work:

```
...
<form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search" ng-submit="doGreeting()">
...
```